# Problem with Web-Alias and WooCommerce

Tags: domain

I have a site with a WooCommerce shop that works just great. I have another domain for which I have setup a Web-Alias pointing to that shop.
It also works great until I put something in the cart. Then it says that item is placed in the cart but the cart is still empty!

I have updated everything, cleared the cache, checked with the webhost but ended up with nothing.

Any idea what may cause this?

Comment: by alias do you mean a CNAME record?  Can you be more specific? Keep in mind that WooCommerce questions are offtopic here, 3rd party plugin support questions are not in this stacks scope

Comment: Yes, its a CNAME record, settings made by me host to forward to another domain, but keep the first domain in the adressbar. I don't know if this is a WooCommerce issue or a something else.